# How to implement row versioning in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to make an integer column on a Postgres table that will store a unique number for each record, where the number for a record will be updated automatically whenever that record is created or updated and where, when the number is updated, it becomes 1 greater than the highest value in that column in the table.

In effect, row versioning. (Sorry for terribly worded explanation - I'm tired!)

My table is like this:

```
create table test1
(
    id          serial not null
        constraint test1_pk
            primary key,
    column_1    integer,
    column_2    varchar,
    row_version bigint
);

alter table test1
    owner to root;

create unique index test1_id_uindex
    on test1 (id);

create unique index test1_row_version_uindex
    on test1 (row_version);
```

And I made a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_row_version()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) THEN
      NEW.row_version = (select max(row_version) from test1) + 1;
      RETURN NEW;
   ELSE
      RETURN OLD;
   END IF;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER update_row_version BEFORE UPDATE ON test1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_row_version();
```

But `row_version` is never updated - it remains null for any records I insert or update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `if new is distinct from old then ...`

Comment: If you do not set the value on Insert it will be NULL when your trigger files on Update. But max(null) is still null and null + 1 is null. So the result after update is still null. You can change table definition  to *row_version bigint default  1*.  But a word of caution. Using max+1 in a multiple user environment is a virtual guarantee you will get duplicates. If user1 updates a row then user2 updates another row before user1 commits user2 gets the same max value.

Comment: I am questioning the underlying idea: why not just increase the previous version? What's the point of considering other rows in the table?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I need to get all the rows that changed since I last checked, so 'select * from test1 where row_version > X'

Comment: Then use a modification timestamp. The method you suggested is vulnerable to race conditions with concurrent inserts.

Comment: A timestamp is not unique so I may get the same row several times. But maybe I misunderstand - please could you write an answer about timestamps? If it does what I need then I'll accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "COALESCE" in your trigger.

Change this line

```
NEW.row_version = (select max(row_version) from test1) + 1;
```

with this

```
NEW.row_version =COALESCE( (select max(row_version) from test1),0) + 1;
```